# Capistrano does not include recipes book

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I wrote small capistrano book https://github.com/umerkulovb/crecipes I'm using in my project.

However it does not work, when I add `require 'crecipes'` in my Capfile.
It gives me error:

```
rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- crecipes (LoadError)
```

MyGemfile:

```
gem 'crecipes', git: "git://github.com/umerkulovb/crecipes.git"
```

What is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

If you execute in your app root

```
gem list
```

is crecipes in the list? Or better, lists

gem list | grep crecipes

anything?

Answer (score 0):

I found error. I must execute 

`bundle update crecipes`

and everything is ok